# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session 5

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2

I've some error to solve, here is the error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
at model.Teacher_$$_jvstd69_0.toString(Teacher_$$_jvstd69_0.java)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:517)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:540)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:357)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
at org.primefaces.component.column.Column.renderChildren(Column.java:344)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:1019)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:967)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:878)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:825)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:788)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:281)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:243)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

it's happen after relation 2 table that i generate from Hibernate tool

for table Student

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "student", schema = "public")
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3484556118289412550L;
    private int stuId;
    private Teacher teacher;
    private String stuName;
    private Integer stuAge;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int stuId) {
        this.stuId = stuId;
    }

    public Student(int stuId, Teacher teacher, String stuName, Integer stuAge) {
        this.stuId = stuId;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.stuName = stuName;
        this.stuAge = stuAge;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "stu_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getStuId() {
        return this.stuId;
    }

    public void setStuId(int stuId) {
        this.stuId = stuId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stu_teachid")
    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return this.teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Column(name = "stu_name", length = 40)
    public String getStuName() {
        return this.stuName;
    }

    public void setStuName(String stuName) {
        this.stuName = stuName;
    }

    @Column(name = "stu_age")
    public Integer getStuAge() {
        return this.stuAge;
    }

    public void setStuAge(Integer stuAge) {
        this.stuAge = stuAge;
    }

}
```

Teacher

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher", schema = "public")
public class Teacher implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3863374948774698083L;
    private int teachId;
    private String teachName;
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>(0);

    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher(int teachId) {
        this.teachId = teachId;
    }

    public Teacher(int teachId, String teachName, Set<Student> students) {
        this.teachId = teachId;
        this.teachName = teachName;
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "teach_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getTeachId() {
        return this.teachId;
    }

    public void setTeachId(int teachId) {
        this.teachId = teachId;
    }

    @Column(name = "teach_name", length = 40)
    public String getTeachName() {
        return this.teachName;
    }

    public void setTeachName(String teachName) {
        this.teachName = teachName;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teacher")
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return this.students;
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

}
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="model"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="service"></context:component-scan>

    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <!-- Create Data Source bean -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/university" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Define SessionFactory bean -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.Student</value>
                <value>model.Teacher</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />


    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to avoid the Lazy Initialization Exception:

1. Set the lazy property to false in the mapping file.I don’t recommend this approach because it will increment the database load and therefore, it will produce a decrease in performance.
2. Keep the session open. Don't close the session before you have processed the data. If the session is open during the request you could get the associated graph but you need to be sure that the action takes within the same transaction.
3. Eagerly fetch the associations. In the HQL query use the keyword "fetch" to retrieve the association. From my point of view this is the best solution to avoid the lazy initialization problem. In HQL, you just need to add the fetch keyword in the from clause to eagerly fetch an association.

Comment: Thxq For your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the mapping of set of students from LAZY to EAGER

Comment: actually you would do well to not use eager fetch. It is a good recipe to shot yourself in the foot with it later.